# Is there a tool to search inside both unicode and ANSI text files from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have tried to use findstr and even windows explorer but I can't get it to find text inside of unicode files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GNU grep for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)

should support Unicode transparently (apparently 2.5.2 is much better than 2.5.1 in this respect)

Also the grep included in [Windows SFU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_Services_for_UNIX#Subsystem_for_UNIX-based_Applications_.28SUA.29) is I believe capable of handling unicode or Ascii files transparently.

There are quite a few comercial windows grep replacements/alikes which claim to support unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Instead of using, for example, **grep -i "username" *.log**
simply use **type *.log | grep -i "username"**